# How can I tell if a specific button in a Bootstrap Modal has been clicked in my JQuery function?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-modal

Here's the situation: My function displays a modal that contains a table of all classes for a student.  That modal has two buttons, a Cancel and Dismiss Student.  If the user clicks the Dismiss Student button, I want my function to know and take the `attendeeClasses` data and act on it (basically, I'm just going to loop through each class and mark that student as dismissed).

I was thinking that I'd have to create an event handler for the click event on the button, but wouldn't I have to put that handler within this function?  I mean, if the handler was outside of this function (the one that displays the modal), then the handler can't access the data (like the list of classes).  I'm a little new to JQuery, so I don't know if there's a way to set a global variable so that both the event handler and the function that displays the modal can access it.

Here's my JQuery:

```
function GetAllClassessForAttendee(classAttendeeId, attendanceStatus, topicAttendanceId) {
    var classesTable = $("#attendeeClasses tbody");

    $.ajax({
        url: "/Class/GetAllClassAttendanceForEmployee/",
        type: "GET",
        data: { classAttendeeId: classAttendeeId, topicAttendanceId: topicAttendanceId, attendanceStatus: attendanceStatus, __RequestVerificationToken: $('input[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').val() },
        beforeSend: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
            $("#loadingImage").show();
        },
        complete: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
            $("#loadingImage").hide();
        },
        success: function (attendeeClasses) {
            $.each(attendeeClasses, function(i, attendeeClass) {
                classesTable.append(
                    '<tr><td>'
                    + attendeeClass.Date
                    + '</td><td>'
                    + attendeeClass.EmployeeName
                    + '</td><td>'
                    + attendeeClass.Topic
                    + '</td></tr>'
                );
            });

            // Display a list of attended classes in Bootstrap modal
            $("#classes").dataTable({
                "bRetrieve": true,
                "bPaginate": false,
                "bFilter": false,
                "aoColumnDefs":[
                    {"aTargets": [ "_all" ], "bSortable": false}
                ]
            });

            $("#dismissalModal").modal('show');

            // If dismiss button is clicked
            // handle the dismissal of student 
            // from each class
            // TODO: Insert code here

        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            if (xhr.responseText !== "") {
                alertify.alert(xhr.responseText);
                alertify.error(xhr.responseText);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Here is the HTML for the modal that gets displayed:

```
 <!-- Modal HTML -->
    <div id="dismissalModal" class="modal fade">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Confirmation</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>Are you sure you want to dismiss the student from these classes?</p>
                    <p class="text-warning"><small>Press Cancel to leave this dialog.</small></p>
                    <table id="attendeeClasses">
                        <thead><tr><th>Date</th><th>Attendee</th><th>Topic</th></tr></thead>
                        <tbody></tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="dismissBtn">Dismiss Student</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

For reference: Here's a pic of the bootstrap modal that's displayed:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to put the event handler within the function. In fact you almost certainly shouldn't - it will re-create the handler every time you call the function, which is unnecessary. Your statement *if the handler was outside of this function (the one that displays the modal), then the handler can't access the data (like the list of classes)* is true, assuming you mean the JSON data in the attendeeClasses variable. You can remedy that by storing it in a global variable when it arrives.

Put the handler outside your function, but within the document.ready handler:

```
var attendeeClassesGlobal = []; //global to store attendees

$(document.ready(function() {
  $("#dismissBtn").click(function(event) {
    //do whatever you want with attendeeClassesGlobal here
  });
});
```

In your ajax "success" function, add one extra line to store the attendee list in the global variable:

```
success: function (attendeeClasses) {
  attendeeClassesGlobal = attendeeClasses;
  //...etc
}
```

One other thing:

```
$("#classes").dataTable({...
```

I can't see any element with id="classes" in your sample. Did you mean "#attendeeClasses"?

Comment: You are correct, I did mean to have #attendeeClasses there.  I pasted in old code.

Also, thank you very much for your help.  I'll mark this as the answer as soon as the timer is up.